# Complex Log inequality $\log{\frac{z}{w}} \neq \log{w}- \log{z}$

Tags: complex-analysis

Assume $w = 2+4\mathrm i$ and let $z$ be unknown, I'm trying to figure out for which values $z = a+b\mathrm i$ we have the following $\log\left(\dfrac zw\right) \neq \log(z) - \log(2+4\mathrm i)$.

My thought process was  that for the principal branch $(-\pi,\pi)$ if the combined arguments $\arg(z)-\arg(w)=-\pi$. For example, using $z=-2-4\mathrm i$ However, this doesn't just turn the expression non-equal, it makes it undefined. Is there something I need to take into account to understand the problem?

Comment: How do you define $\log(z)$?

Comment: Log(z) = ln(|z|)+iArg(z) is how i would define the complex logarithm, hence Log(z/w) = ln(|z|)-ln(|w|)+i(Arg(z)-Arg(w))

Comment: First of all, I'm assuming that the range of Arg is $(-\pi, \pi].$  From this, it looks like your latest comment is wrong, because [Arg(z) - Arg(w)] might not be in the range of Arg.

Comment: Maybe I'm calculating this all wrong lets say that w = -1+i,  $Arg(z) = 3\pi/4$. What I now don't understand is for what principal argument of z=a+bi my non-equality becomes true?

Comment: I think I might get it now, the non-equality becomes true whenever the two arguments is outside of the range $(-\pi,\pi)$, as per example, w=-1+i which gives $Arg(w)=3\pi/4$, now if z has some Arg, $Arg(z)-3\pi/4 < -\pi$ So any value smaller than $Arg(z)=-\pi/4$ means we are outside of the range.